# Is there a way to parse a application manifest?

Tags: c#, clickonce, manifest

I am looking for a way to have the hosting website parse out the [appname].manifest file to pull out the application name, version, and icon if available. This way I can put it into a control for easy deployment. Are there any framework calls that will assist me in parsing out the manifest file?

The files I am looking for are [appname].application and/or [appname].manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get *most* of the info you want using the `System.Deployment.Application.InPlaceHostingManager` class - don't be fooled by the name, it is primarily for browser-hosted ClickOnce apps, but also works for standalone ClickOnce apps. Once you initialise an instance and pass it the URL to the .application file, you can call `GetManifestAsync()` - in the event handler for `GetManifestCompleted`, you can get the application name and version:

```
void iphm_GetManifestCompleted(object sender, GetManifestCompletedEventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Application name: {0}", e.ApplicationIdentity);
    Console.WriteLine("Application version: {0}", e.Version);
}
```

The icon is usually referenced in the application manifest (.application is the deployment manifest) - the app manifest can be accessed using `InPlaceHostingManager`; in the above example, you'd get the value from `e.ApplicationManifest` which would give you an `XmlReader` to play with.

Probably best to study the relevant XML schema(s) and then find the icon using XQuery.

Comment: This gives me most of what I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.aspx) will do most of the heavy lifting for you. It'll extract meta-data from a file to determine the assembly's Product Name & Version. As for the Icon, that's a different story, but at least this is a start for you:

*Update:*

Also using [System.Reflection.Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx) you can call `GetManifestResourceInfo(string)`, `GetManifestResourceNames()`, and `GetManifestResourceStream(string)` to access an assembly’s resources (for the Icon).

Comment: thank you; however, I am looking for the parses that will parse the *.application and/or the *.manifest xml based files. In a clickonce application the xml application and manifest files are now the same as the binary encoded ones.